# Create dynamic rows and columns in html twig

Tags: php, drupal, twig

I have the below code working on a twig file:

```
<div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-responsive-grid views-responsive-grid-horizontal views-columns-12 container-12">
           <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-first">
              <div class="grid-2 views-column-1">
                 <div class="views-field views-field-field-seal">
                    <div class="field-content"><a href="/link1" class="content-processed"><img src="/sites/default/files/mainimage1.png" width="121" height="121"></a></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-2 views-column-2">
                 <div class="views-field views-field-field-seal">
                    <div class="field-content"><a href="/link2" class="content-processed"><img src="/sites/default/files/mainimage2.png" width="121" height="121"></a></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This code generates the output as below:

[image]

this means, it's correctly generating 2 columns with images on one row. I want to convert this code dynamically using loop.

In the place of image I want to replace with {{ field.field_image.content }} and in place of the URL I want to replace with {{ field.field_url.content }}

I want to do this with twig batching but need help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your collection is called `fields`,

```html
<div class="view-content">
    {% for row in fields|batch(2) %}
    <div class="views-responsive-grid views-responsive-grid-horizontal views-columns-12 container-12">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-first">
            {% for field in row %}
            <div class="grid-2 views-column-{{ loop.index }}">
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-seal">
                    <div class="field-content"><a href="{{ field.field_url.content }}" class="content-processed"><img src="{{ field.field_image.content }}" width="121" height="121"></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/y9fqui)